# Send variable from client side to server side

Tags: javascript

I've been looking for information on how I can send a client side variable to the server side using JavaScript. I'm a beginner and working on my first full stack web app and essentially i want to do something like this;

```
var userInput = $('#location-city').val();
```

This is taking in the value of a `<input id="location-city">` in my html file on the client side.

I want to send this variable `userInput` to the server side where I use it with an API in the following manner:

```
baseUrl + userInput
```

This would add the `userInput` (which would be a city) to the `baseUrl` of my API and then return locations in a certain city. The reason why my API needs to stay on server side is because I'm using secret id's and tokens.

Comment: Did you use the search and had a look at any of the questions/answers in [`[javascript] pass variable to server`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+pass+variable+to+server)? If not, please do that before asking a new question.

Comment: Perhaps this post too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014257/sending-data-from-a-browser-to-a-server-and-back

Comment: Could you give me more detail,sir? I thought you just need to get GET PARAMETER in your server side and use GET URL in your client side, but  give me more info anyway.

Comment: You should look at the jquery api for http and Ajax they have functions that can handle this

Comment: Take a look at this question [transfer-data-from-one-html-file-to-another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17502071/transfer-data-from-one-html-file-to-another) it can solve your problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to I send data from JavaScript to PHP and vice versa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968296/how-to-i-send-data-from-javascript-to-php-and-vice-versa)

Comment: so ive looked through those resources and alot of them are using c++ or ASP.NET which I'm not using either.  The examples are also transferring global variables to different html files...I'm trying to send mine from a main.js file to a server.js file...