# Ajax function learning

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need help in Ajax.
I got this code online.
This function is to check the `contact.php`

I have some few question so someone could assist me.
My questions :
 1. Is this code good and possible to run ? 
 2. Can someone explain me what does the function in line 4 and line 5 does.It seems it send data to the contact.php but what is it returning?

Ajax:

```
var validateEmailForm = {
dataType: 'json',
        submit: function(form) {
        var redirect = false;
         $.ajax('contact.php', {data:{'email':form.email.value}}).done(function(data) {
       if ( typeof(data) == 'object' ) {
                    if ( data.status == 'valid') {
                        form.submit();
                    } else if(data.status !=='valid' {     
               alert('The e-mail address entered is wrong.');
                      }
                } else {
                    alert('Failed to connect to the server.');
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

Contact.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

$email = $_POST['email'];
if (isset($_$POST['email']))
{
  // How to return valid to the ajax
} else {
  // How to return invalid to the ajax.
}

?>
```

Comment: Re: your questions:
1) "Good" is subjective.
2) Try it and see.

Comment: @Celeo , my problem is with the PHP .. I'm wondering how to send data.status == valid to the ajax.. I kept on trying and fail that's why i'm posting on stackoverflow.

Comment: Have you tried adding debug statements to actually see what it returns?

Comment: [Documentation for the AJAX call can be found here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: Has your question been answered satisfactorily? *If yes, please choose an accepted answer (or write your own and accept that) in order to close the question.* If not, please post additional information so that we can try to help.

Comment: @gibberish , haven't yet sir.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is much easier than it sounds. You just need to see a few good examples.

Try these:

[A simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734395/form-inside-of-load-not-posting-correctly/13734466#13734466)

[More complicated example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887098/two-post-requests-one-after-the-other-second-post-request-doesnt-get-execut/17887642#17887642)

[Populate dropdown 2 based on selection in dropdown 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16924082/dynamic-drop-down-box/16924652#16924652)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25945137/php-fetch-content-from-one-form-and-update-it-in-other-form/25954450#25954450

---

The above examples demonstrate a few things:

(1) There are four *formats* for an AJAX request - the full `$.ajax()` structure, and three shortcut structures (`$.post()`, `$.get()`, and `$.load()` )

Until you are pretty good at AJAX, I suggest using a correctly formatted `$.ajax()` code block, which is what the above examples demonstrate. Such a code block looks like this:

```
$('#formID').submit({
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
         url: 'contact.php', 
    dataType: 'json',
        data: 'email=' + form.email.value
    }).done(function(data) {
        if ( typeof(data) == 'object' ) {
            if ( data.status == 'valid') {
                form.submit();
            } else if(data.status !=='valid' {     
                alert('The e-mail address entered is wrong.');
                return false;
            } else {
                alert('Failed to connect to the server.');
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

(2) In an `$.ajax()` code block, the `data:` line specifies the data that is sent to the PHP processor file.

(3) The `dataType:` line specifies the type of data that the ajax code block *expects to receive back from* the PHP processor file. The default dataType is html, unless otherwise specified.

(4) In the PHP processor file, data is returned to the AJAX code block via the `echo` command. Whether that data is returned as html, text, or json, it is `echo`ed back to the AJAX routine, like this:

```
<?php

//perform MySQL search here. For eg, get array $result with: $result['firstname'] and $result['lastname']

$out =  '<div id="myresponse">';
$out .= 'First Name: <input type="text" value="' .$result['firstname']. '" />';
$out .= 'Last Name: <input type="text" value="' .$result['lastname']. '" />';
$out .= '</div>';

echo $out;
```

Please try a couple of the above examples for yourself and you will see how it works.

It is not necessary to use `json` to send/return data. However, `json` is a useful format to send ***array*** data, but as you can see, you can construct a full html response on the PHP side and echo back the finished markup.

---

So, to definitively answer your second question, you just need to `echo` back some data. It is the job of the PHP file to:

(1) receive the data from the AJAX routine,

(2) Use that data in a look up of some kind (usually in a database),

(3) Construct a response, and

(4) `echo` (NOT `return`) the response back to the AJAX routine's `success:` or `.done()` functions.

Comment: These are echo ? I'm looking for value deterrent in PHP that returns like OhGodWhy posted.

Comment: See updated answer. *Please experiment with the simplified examples included at top.* Note that json is a great format for sending array data, but it introduces a level of complexity that might not be necessary at this point in your AJAX career.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a JSON_encoded array to the ajax function, like below:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$status = false;
if (isset($_$POST['email']))
{
     $status = 'success'
} else {
     $status = false
}
echo json_encode(array('status' => $status));
```

?>

Further, add `dataType: 'json'` to your `$.ajax()` so that the deferred function automatically parses it as such.

Remove the `typeof()` as we know what we're expecting in return.

Comment: Could you help me for the line in the datatype json?
I'm new to JSON , i only know ajax and php :(

Comment: So i'll need to change my ajax conditions instead of valid , change to success & false?

Comment: I just edited my ajax with the datatype..Please let me know if i'm correct or wrong thanks in advance.