# Setting HTML Attribute via PHP File

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm new to PHP and seem to have ran into a problem I can't seem to get around.

I have a form on a secure page that creates a PHP file to store a text value. I named this variable `$text`.

The Form HTML Code:

```
<form action="upload_title.php" method="post">
  <label for="text">Title 1:</label>
  <input type="text" name="text" id="text"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The `upload_title.php` then seems to store the text input as `$text` in `filename.php`:

```
<?php
  $var_str = var_export($_POST['text'], true);
  $var = "<?php\n\n\$text = $var_str;\n\n?>";
  file_put_contents('filename.php', $var);
?>
```

This seems to be functional as the form will generate `filename.php`, below is an example if I typed `Store` into the form input and submitted on the webpage.

```
<?php
  $text = 'Store';
?>
```

Now the issue I'm encountering is not being able to retrieve this stored as a attribute in separate html document, the `index.html` in my case.

This was my best approach to changing the `title` attribute of an image:

```
<a href="upload/1.jpg">
  <img src="upload/thumb.jpg" title="<?php include 'filename.php'; echo htmlspecialchars($text); ?>" alt="" class="image0">
</a>
```

This does not work, but I can see my JQuery detects that this is trying to be populated but does not extract the data from `filename.php` on the `index.htm' page.

Thank those in advance for your advice and insight, it is sincerely appreciated.

Comment: Instead of storing in a file store it in a SESSION variable that you have access to throughout your application. [PHP Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

Comment: Why are you using PHP as storage?! That's not quite what it's for, and there are far better ways.

Comment: You will do yourself an enormous service by learning just the basics of AJAX and using that. Don't be intimidated -- it's much easier than you may think. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26092158/can-i-use-dynamic-contents-in-a-tabbed-page-when-it-refreshes-it-goes-to-the/26103445#26103445

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @JayBlanchard ! I'm not too sure that this would be applicable to what I'm going for as the changes made are not just in a user session, but actually being referenced by the public html of the index. I'm going for using the form input on a secure page to be loaded to a PHP file that will affect the public html.

Comment: Thanks @Biffen! I'm definitely not going for anything crazy technical, it's just to change an attribute that's being used by my JQuery that can be changed by a user using a a form input. Is there no way to get the $text value to be referenced from the filename.php in the index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is probably the fact that you are using an `html` file instead of a `php` file, in this case `index.html`.

Your server is likely not set up by default to process `.html` files as php so the php does not get executed.

Apart from that it is not a very good way to store your value as when the php does get executed, you introduce a security risk and you use a lot more storage than necessary. You'd better store the value in a database or text file.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @jeroen ! The value is really not a huge risk to the site, nor would I care even if it was compromised or befell greater storage usage. Is there no way to amend a HTML page to run PHP and retrieve the $text value from the external PHP?

Comment: @NickolasBarakso Until someone sends in something like `''; exec('rm -fr /');`

Comment: I do understand that i'm leaving a risk but it is just for a small site that I'm pretty certain hackers or the general public will more than likely never see. Excuse my ignorance but I would assume that bit of code clears my local site or something? Even if this happened, I can back it up. Would you say that there is another way to alter an html attribute coming from a data base, but wouldn't that use php too? Would changing the .htaccess allow me to run php within html?

Comment: @NickolasBarakso Just store the value and use `file_get_contents()` to get it back. No php needed for the file with the value.

Comment: Thanks @jeroen, I'm tinkering with it now to no avail, how, if it is possible to implement the attribute in the html with the file_get_contents() in the html without PHP? Isn't the file_get_contets() a PHP function? How would I mark the title attribute in the html to retrieve the value using this?

Comment: @NickolasBarakso Something like `title="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents('filename.txt')); ?>"`. Assuming a simple text file with just the value.

Comment: No such luck, this does not seem to render as an actual text value that my JQuery can pick up or it's not able to retrieve the contents. Just made a test.txt with only 'text' as its contents but it did not render on the index through the attribute

Comment: @NickolasBarakso You'll still need to change the file that does contain php to a php file. You could use an .htaccess file, but you'd have to search for the correct syntax, I don't have that here on my phone.

Comment: Thanks @jeroen or pointing me in the right direction. I just got it work, your a life-saver :D