# Is there a way to submit multiple forms to insert data in specific column?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this form, but I need to use it for more users.
ex for user_id=1 to submit 1 form for user_id=2 to submit another form,
can you guys help?

The database table has a column u_userid where 1 = admin 2,3,4,5,6,7 is normal user, each user has more columns which I need to update data from database.

```
<?php
if( $_SESSION['user_id'] == '1' || $_SESSION['user_id'] == '7' )
{
    echo '<hr class="mx-3 my-0">
            <div class="callout callout-warning m-0 py-3">
              <div>
                <strong>Sas Andreea</strong>
              </div>
              <small class="text-muted mr-3"><i class="icon-calendar"></i>Salariu Lunar:</small>
              <small class="text-muted"><i class="icon-location-pin"></i><input type="text"  name="salariulunar" value="' . $row[
  'salariulunar'] . '"  maxlength="4" size="4"> lei 
              <br /> Data contract: <input type="text"  name="datacontractului"  maxlength="10" size="7" value="' . $row['datacontractului'] . ' ">
              <br /> Datorie: <input type="text"  name="datorie" value="' . $row['datorie'] . '"   maxlength="4" size="4"> Lei
              <br /> Salariu in avans: <input type="text" value="' . $row['salariuavans'] . ' " name="salariuavans"  maxlength="4" size="4"> Lei
              <br /> Zile de concediu luate: <input  type="text" value="' . $row['zileconcediu'] . '"  name="zileconcediu"  maxlength="2" size="2"> Zile
              </small>
            </div>';
}
?>
<!-- Sfarsit angajat -->
<?php
if( $_SESSION['user_id'] == '1' )
{
    echo '<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o" ></i> Modifica</button>';
}
?> 
</form>
```

Comment: I didn’t even understand the question

Comment: _"when it should insert it only on user id = 2"_ That's not what your `if` statement is doing...

Comment: You can’t insert for specific user id you can only select, delete, and edit the record

Comment: So are you _inserting_ or _updating_? You should include the code that handles the form submit.  And "it insert the data from form for all users" isn't understandable at all.

Comment: Well im actually updating

Comment: Hi Pirjol - has your question been answered? Do you have any further parts to _this_ question that we can help with? If your question has been more-or-less answered by someone below, please use the checkmark to choose a best answer and to close out this question. Also, please upvote any answers that you found helpful (you can also upvote the "correct" answer if it was helpful). Otherwise, please *edit* your question to explain how we can help further.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it by making the If statement like this...
      If($_SESSION['user_id'] == '2')
    {

Use the update feature and then add a ‘where user_id = 1’ in the end of your statement

Comment: i dont think $_session will solve something, because i allready have a session started

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. You can use a form, which requires that you have the 
   `<form action="nameOfYourBackEndFile.php" method="post">`
          Your existing stuff in here
   `</form>`
    tags surrounding your existing code *AND* you need a button `type="submit"` to submit the form.

or

2. You can use javascript/jQuery. Either way is fine.

Also, you need a way to identify which user this form is being filled out for. You have the `user_id` in a session variable, so why not use that? Your submit button can look like this:

```
<button id="submit_<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; />" type="submit">Go</button>
```

See this example for more information about what you are trying to do:

[How can I make, when clicking a button, send an email with the data included from the form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28997765/how-can-i-make-when-clicking-a-button-send-an-email-with-the-data-included-fro/28998949#28998949)

[PHP - Secure member-only pages with a login system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734297/php-secure-member-only-pages-with-a-login-system/34735490#34735490)

[AJAX request callback using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973386/ajax-request-callback-using-jquery/17974843#17974843)

Comment: if you watch here https://jsfiddle.net/k8pjfr0h/ you will understand what i mean. aftear each STRONG text there is user informations that only admin (me) can edit , the users can only see they'r info

Comment: You really have multiple questions. Your first question is, `"How do I send the information typed by a user to a back-end file so that it can be added into a MySQL database"`. Your next question is, `"How do I receive data from a form or from ajax in a back-end PHP file?"`. Your third question is `"How do I update an existing record in MySQL with new data, and then return an answer to the user?"` You should study the examples I provided - read them over and over until you understand - and then try to implement your solution. By the way, AJAX is the way to go. Forms are so pre-2000.

Comment: Sorry, please do not misunderstand. I was not being critical. I was attempting to help you understand your needs. It is a good idea to break down a complex task into smaller steps. Take each task by itself and solve that. One step at a time.

Comment: its ok :D dont worry m8t :P