# How to make an Ajax Contact Form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

P.S. edited to remove unnecessary code

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong here?
The error log doesn't show a thing.

Here's my html, js, and php.

**sample.js**

```js
        // this is to prevent page refresh, right?        
        stepsForm.prototype.options = {
      onSubmit : function() { return false; }
     };

     // submits the form, but i add some js in sample.html, so this one will not work.
     stepsForm.prototype._submit = function() {
      this.options.onSubmit( this.el );
     }
```

**sample.html**

```html
<div class="container">

  <section>
    <form id="theForm" class="simform" autocomplete="off" action="form-process.php">
      <div class="simform-inner">
        <ol class="questions">
          <li>
            <span><label for="q1">What's your name / full name?</label></span>
            <input id="q1" name="q1" type="text" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <span><label for="q2">What's your email address?</label></span>
            <input id="q2" name="q2" type="text" data-validate="email" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <span><label for="q3">What's your phone number?</label></span>
            <input id="q3" name="q3" type="text" data-validate="phone" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <span><label for="q4">Type your question below?</label></span>
            <input id="q4" name="q4" type="text" />
          </li>
        </ol>
        <!-- /questions -->
        <button class="submit" type="submit">Send answers</button>
        <div class="controls">
          <button class="next"></button>
          <div class="progress"></div>
          <span class="number">
            <span class="number-current"></span>
          <span class="number-total"></span>
          </span>
          <span class="error-message"></span>
        </div>
        <!-- / controls -->
      </div>
      <!-- /simform-inner -->
      <span class="final-message"></span>
    </form>
    <!-- /simform -->
  </section>
</div>
<!-- /container -->
<script src="js/classie.js"></script>
<script src="js/stepsForm.js"></script>

<!-- this is the script that will replace the one in the sample.js -->
<script>
  var theForm = document.getElementById('theForm');

  new stepsForm(theForm, {
    onSubmit: function(form) {
      classie.addClass(theForm.querySelector('.simform-inner'), 'hide');
      var name = $("#q1").val();
      var email = $("#q2").val();
      var number = $("#q3").val();
      var message = $("#q4").val();

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "form-process.php",
        data: JSON.stringify({
          name: name,
          email: email,
          number: number,
          message: message
        }),
        success: function(response) {
          var data = response.d;
          var messageEl = theForm.querySelector('.final-message');
          messageEl.innerHTML = 'Thank you! We\'ll be in touch.';
          classie.addClass(messageEl, 'show');
        }
      });
    }
  });
</script>
```

**sample.php**

```html
 $EmailTo = "mail@mail.com";
    $Subject = "New Message Received";

    // prepare email body text
    $Body = "";
    $Body .= "Name: ";
    $Body .= $name;
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "Email: ";
    $Body .= $email;
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "Phone Number: ";
    $Body .= $number;
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "Message: ";
    $Body .= $message;
    $Body .= "\n";

    // send email
    $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From:".$email);

    // redirect to success page
```

so the step for this process is get the input from html, process it with ajax (js), then send it to **sample.php** to mail it, right?
but I cant seem to pass the ajax process or sample.php. my code result in blank page and no outgoing email.

Since I'm new to php and js, I mostly reverse engineer the source to make it suitable for me. This time I have taken the "minimalist form interface" from codrops.

and this is also my first post in SO, so please be gentle :)

Comment: I don't think you could have pasted anymore code....can you maybe try and point out at least up to what point this does work?

Comment: "explain me the concept of ajax form" This isn't the place ask for an explanation  of a concept. Learn about what you want to do, and if you find your code has a specific problem come back and ask about it.

Comment: `what the code means and do (per line).` - you've posted **FIVE HUNDRED** lines of what you call "my code" and you want a per line explanation? good luck buddy

Comment: Oh dang I didn't read the bottom part, I was too overwhelmed with the sheer amount of script. It's very unlikely you will get a volunteer to comment each line to tell you what it does.....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed some capitalisation issues with your post.  Please note this forum is not to ask about concepts.  You can try other forums for explanation about ajax.

Comment: i have improved the question, please take a look at it :)

Comment: How did this project go? If you solved your problem, then **to close this question** please either **(1)** choose a correct answer (click checkmark beside answer, or **(2)** add your own answer and tell everyone how you solved your problem. *Who knows? You might get some upvotes.*

Answer (score 1):

You chose a very complicated example. Here is a MUCH simpler AJAX contact form to learn from.

**index.php**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!--  Whatever code you have above the contact form  -->

<!--  A very simple contact form -->
<div id="frmContact">
    Name: <input id="name" type="text" />
    Email: <input id="email" type="text" />
    Comment: <textarea id="comment" rows="4" cols="40"></textarea>
    <button id="mybutt">Send</button>
</div>
```

**index.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mybutt').click(function(){
        var na = $('#name').val();
        var em = $('#email').val();
        var cm = $('#comment').val();

        if (na=='' || em=='' || cm==''){
            alert("Please complete all fields");
            return false;
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
             url: 'your_php_ajax_file.php',
            data: 'na='+na+'&em='+em+'&cm='+cm,
            success: function(d){
                if (d.length) alert(d);
            }
        }); //END ajax
    }); //END #mybutt.click
});
```

**your_php_ajax_file.php**

```
<?php

    function sanitize($data) {
        return htmlentities(strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($data)));
    }

    // sanitize your inputs 
    $na = sanitize($_POST['na']);
    $em = sanitize($_POST['em']);
    $cm = sanitize($_POST['cm']);

    $dt = date('Y-M-d H:i:s');

    $body = '
        <div style="width:100%;text-align:center;margin:0 0 30px 0;font-family:Arial;font-size:30px;font-weight:bold;">Website Contact Form</div>
        <div style="text-align:left;margin:10px 0;font-family:Arial;font-size:22px;">'.$dt.'</div>
        <div style="text-align:left;margin:10px 0;font-family:Arial;font-size:22px;">'.$na.'</div>
        <div style="text-align:left;margin:10px 0;font-family:Arial;font-size:22px;">'.$em.'</div>
        <hr style="color:#cccccc;">
        <div style="text-align:left;margin:10px 0;font-family:Arial;font-size:22px;">'.$cm.'</div>
    ';


    $headers = "";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
    $headers .= "From: website@example.com\n";
    $headers .= "Organization: example.com\n";
    $headers .= "X-Priority: 3\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion() ."\n" . PHP_EOL;
    $msg = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">';
    $msg .= $body;

    mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
    mail('youremail@hotmail.com', 'Contat form', $msg, $headers);

    echo 'Contact form sent';
```

---

Regarding AJAX, here are some good posts for getting the basics of AJAX:

[A simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734395/form-inside-of-load-not-posting-correctly/13734466#13734466)

[More complicated example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887098/two-post-requests-one-after-the-other-second-post-request-doesnt-get-execut/17887642#17887642)

[Populate dropdown 2 based on selection in dropdown 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16924082/dynamic-drop-down-box/16924652#16924652)

NB: Note that the PHP `AJAX processor` code cannot be part of the same PHP file (e.g. index.php) that you are calling it from (or else it won't work and the entire page will be echoed back to you as the "ajax response")

Comment: hi, thanks for answering my question. I will try to use your advise (haven't got time to do that, will be back with result) 
in the meantime, i have edited my question, could you please take a look at it once more? :)