# Update img with jquery and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

**i'm trying to update img cover  without refresh the page using ajax  and php  but it does not  work at all**

**HTML**

```
  <div class="cover" >
  <img  id="b1"  src="<?php echo $user->picture_path();>"class="cover"/>          
                <div id="modal-cover" class="cov-lo">        </div>
   </div>
```

**js**

```
$('#b2').on({
    'click': function(){ 
     $('#b1').attr('src', <?php echo $user->picture_path();?> + '?' + new Date().getTime());}
});
```

**the input and form**

```
   <form  action="profile.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"  > 
            <div class="hio"> 
                                        Upload                                   <input  type="file" onchange="this.form.submit()" name="cover" id="bla2"class="custom-file-input" /> 
 </div> 
             </form>
```

Comment: it's old id in input bla2 is right one even with right one will not  work my friend

Comment: @HossamElddinMagdy Please update your question and make it clear. What does "not working" mean? Have you checked the JS console?

Answer (score 2):

Ajax would look more like this:

**js/jQuery:**

```
$(document).on({'click', '#b2', function(){ 
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
         url: 'my_ajax_processor_file.php',
        data: '',
        success: function(data){
            $('#b1').attr('src', data);
        }
    }); //END ajax

}); //END #b2.click
```

**my_ajax_processor_file.php:**

```
<?php 
    $dt = new Date().getTime();
    $pp = 'get user picture path here';
    echo $pp .' - '. $pp;
```

Note that you need to have an external PHP file, which I've called `my_ajax_processor_file.php`, that does some additional PHP processing and `ECHO`s back a value.

This value is received in the AJAX code block's `success` function, and called `data` (call it what you like - the name is set here: `function(data)`.

Note that the contents of `data` variable are only available within that success function.

---

Here are some more basic examples of what AJAX looks like:

[A simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734395/form-inside-of-load-not-posting-correctly/13734466#13734466)

[More complicated example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887098/two-post-requests-one-after-the-other-second-post-request-doesnt-get-execut/17887642#17887642)

[Populate dropdown 2 based on selection in dropdown 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16924082/dynamic-drop-down-box/16924652#16924652)

Comment: care to see where the OP used your code? [In a new question...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624394/how-to-call-back-img-src-oop-php) which I closed as an exact duplicate.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of where the PHP and HTML are interpreted:

1. PHP is a server-side scripting language designed for web development (see [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP)). That means that **the PHP code is executed on the server before arriving in the browser**.
2. HTML is interpreted as plain text by the browser. **No PHP is executed in the browser.**

Therefore, once the JS gets to the browser, `echo $user->picture_path();` has already been executed and is interpreted as plain text by the browser.

Your JS will look like this once it hits the browser:

```
$('#b2').on({
    'click': function() {
        $('#b1').attr('src', '/the/path/to/the/picture' + '?' + new Date().getTime());
    }
});
```

Comment: Even though you're right, I have a feeling this isn't the case here because of the `+ '?' + new Date().getTime()` at the end. I'm assuming that's some way to guarantee a new image. Then again, I could be wrong and that part is just pointless.